# User control does not dispose when dispose is called

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I am using user control following way:

```
 Login = new MainMenu();
            Login.Parent = this;
            Login.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Login.SelectionMade += new LoginS.SelectionMadeDelegate(menu_SelectionMade);
            Login.Show();
```

At some point, the user control fires an event, on which main form reacts like this:

```
   login.SelectionMade -= this.login_SelectionMade;
                    login.Dispose();
```

However when checking in debugger, the login instance is still not null. Why? It should be disposed I think

Answer (score 3):

Calling dispose on an object does not set it to null. Dispose would clean up any resources used in the Login control.

You should use:

```
Login.Dispose();
Login = null;
```

Comment: Lol, I did not know that, thanks. Simple setting login to null will not cause the same (if there are no other references?)

Comment: @Mocco: No, that will mean the control can be garbage collected, which isn't the same as it being disposed.

Comment: you should call dispose before setting the object to null to ensure the resources are cleaned up as soon as possible. Setting the login reference to null only could leave internal resources still in use for a while

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks, but what is the difference if GC clears it or dispose does it? Just that GC will do it unpredictably? Also do I need to unhook the event?